# SQL Query Help - Negative reporting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Perhaps somebody can help with Ideas or a Solution. A User asked me for a negative report. We have a table with tickets each ticket has a ticket number which would be easy to select but the user wants a list of missing tickets between the first and last ticket in the system.

E.g. `Select TicketNr from Ticket order by TicketNr`

```
Result
1,
2,
4,
7,
11
```

But we actually want the result `3,5,6,8,9,10`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ticket](
[pknTicketId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TicketNr] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

SQL Server 2016 - TSQL

Any ideas ?

**So a bit more information is need all solution thus far works on small table. Our production database has over 4 million tickets. Hence why we need to find the missing ones.**

Comment: show the data present your table. Without that it is impossible to help. And also add the RDBMS MSSQL/Oracle/MySql you are using.

Comment: FYI: You mention that you kept hitting maxrecursion problems.  You can add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to prevent that.  Also you mention you went with a temp table.  If you want to improve performance you could hold a list of numbers in a permanent table, and add more to it each time a query needs more numbers than are in the table; so it grows as needed but never shrinks; buying you a bit of performance at the cost of a small amount of space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the minimum and maximum, then generate all posible ticket numbers and finally select the ones that are missing.

```
;WITH FirstAndLast AS
(
    SELECT
        MinTicketNr = MIN(T.TicketNr),
        MaxTicketNr = MAX(T.TicketNr)
    FROM
        Ticket AS T
),
AllTickets AS
(
    SELECT
        TicketNr = MinTicketNr,
        MaxTicketNr = T.MaxTicketNr
    FROM
        FirstAndLast AS T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        TicketNr = A.TicketNr + 1,
        MaxTicketNr = A.MaxTicketNr
    FROM
        AllTickets AS A
    WHERE
        A.TicketNr + 1 <= A.MaxTicketNr
)
SELECT
    A.TicketNr
FROM
    AllTickets AS A
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'missing ticket'
        FROM
            Ticket AS T
        WHERE
            A.TicketNr = T.TicketNr)
ORDER BY
    A.TicketNr
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 32000)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can accept the results in a different format, the following will do what you want:

```
select TicketNr + 1 as first_missing,
       next_TicketNr - 1 as last_missing,
       (next_TicketNr - TicketNr - 1) as num_missing
from (select t.*, lead(TicketNr) over (order by TicketNr) as next_TicketNr
      from Ticket t
     ) t
where next_TicketNr <> TicketNr + 1;
```

This shows each sequence of missing ticket numbers on a single row, rather than a separate row for each of them.

If you do use a recursive CTE, I would recommend doing it only for the missing tickets:

```
with cte as (
      select (TicketNr + 1) as missing_TicketNr
      from (select t.*, lead(TicketNr) over (order by TicketNr) as next_ticketNr
            from tickets t
           ) t
      where next_TicketNr <> TicketNr + 1
      union all
      select missing_TicketNr + 1
      from cte
      where not exists (select 1 from tickets t2 where t2.TicketNr = cte.missing_TicketNr + 1)
     )
select *
from cte;
```

This version starts with the list of missing ticket numbers.  It then adds a new one, as the numbers are not found.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `recursive cte` to find the missing `ticket numbers` :

```
with missing as (
      select min(TicketNr) as mnt, max(TicketNr) as mxt
      from ticket t
      union all
      select mnt+1, mxt
      from missing m
      where mnt < mxt
 )
select m.*
from missing m  
where not exists (select 1 from tickets t where t.TicketNr = m.mnt);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2c1a8/2)

```
declare @ticketsTable table (ticketNo int not null)
insert @ticketsTable (ticketNo) values (1),(2),(4),(7),(11)
;with cte1(ticketNo, isMissing, sequenceNo) AS
(
    select ticketNo
    , 0
    , row_number() over (order by ticketNo) 
    from @ticketsTable
)
, cte2(ticketNo, isMissing, sequenceNo) AS
(
    select ticketNo, isMissing, sequenceNo
    from cte1

    union all

    select a.ticketNo + 1
    , 1
    , a.sequenceNo
    from cte2 a
    inner join cte1 b
    on b.sequenceNo = a.sequenceNo + 1
    and b.ticketNo != a.ticketNo + 1
)
select * 
from cte2 
where isMissing = 1
order by ticketNo
```

It works by collecting all of the existing tickets, marking them as existing, and assigning each a **consecutive** number giving their order in the original list.

We can then see the gaps in the list by finding any spots where the consecutive order number shows the next record, but the ticket numbers are not consecutive.

Finally, we recursively fill in the gaps; working from the start of a gap and adding new records until that gap's consecutive numbers no longer has a gap between the related ticket numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one give you easiest solution

```
with cte as(
select max(TicketNr) maxnum,min(TicketNr) minnum from Ticket )

select a.number FROM master..spt_values a,cte
WHERE Type = 'P' and number < cte.maxnum and number > cte.minno
except 
select TicketNr FROM Ticket
```

Comment: This is simple and works, but won't show numbers higher than the ones stored in `spt_values`.

Comment: yes, that is the problem of master..spt_values table but if you are doing for small numbers then it will be good solution.

Comment: If you want to go over `spt_values` one option is to create a custom function for generating sequential numbers; e.g. `generate_series` per: https://developer42.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/t-sql-generate-series-getting-a-list-of-numbers-in-a-given-range/

Comment: I do like this but unfortunately our tickets range in the millions

Answer (score 0):

So After looking at all the solutions

I went with creating a temp table with a full range of number from Starting to Ending ticket and then select from the Temp table where the ticket number not in the ticket table.

The reason being I kept running in MAXRECURSION problems.